# Ruby daemon decision

Tags: ruby, daemon

I'm aware of some great gems (Daemons, Resque, Starling/Workling, background_job.rb...) to daemonize Ruby tasks, but I'm not sure which to choose in my context.

My daemon is quite simple, it polls a database, looking for jobs. It does not load any framework like Rails. Each job is relatively fast. I need to be sure the daemon is always alive, and it needs to be automatically relaunched if it dies. Target platforms are OSX and Linux.

Which daemon gem would you use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to keep it alive, you might want to try some process management tools like [bluepill](https://github.com/arya/bluepill) or [god](http://god.rubyforge.org/). I used bluepill in the production server and it works fine on both OSX and Linux. Both can daemonize your ruby script as well. :D